# How to delete a pointer to a modeless dialog in WTL

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, wtl

in MainDlg Function

```
LRESULT CMainDlg::OnDo(WORD wNotifyCode, WORD wID, HWND hWndCtl, BOOL& bHandled)
{

    CMyDlg* dlg = new CMyDlg;// it could be CMainDlg member var
    //dlg.pMain = this; // i want to SendMessage(pMain.m_hWnd...) in CMyDlg...but it don't     
    //  work...
    dlg->Create(m_hWnd);
    dlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    return 0;

}
```

in CMyDlg

```
 class CMyDlg : public CDialogImpl<CMyDlg>, public CUpdateUI<CMyDlg>,
public CMessageFilter, public CIdleHandler, 
public CWinDataExchange<CMyDlg>,
public CDialogResize<CMyDlg>


LRESULT CMyDlg::OnCancel(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD wID, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL&   /*bHandled*/)
{
    DestroyWindow();

 }
```

so the CMyDlg* dlg pointer will be lost... (memory leak)

i google for modelss dialog .note that message in msdn.com

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhk0y9cw(VS.80).aspx

note:This sample uses a very simple mechanism: It performs delete this in PostNcDestroy — a function that is called after the nonclient area of the box has been destroyed.

but that's in MFC .I use it for WTL . when delete this; it will be asserted on

```
virtual ~CWindowImplRoot()
{
  #ifdef _DEBUG
    if(m_hWnd != NULL)  // should be cleared in WindowProc
    {
        ATLTRACE(atlTraceWindowing, 0, _T("ERROR - Object deleted before window was destroyed\n"));
        ATLASSERT(FALSE);
    }
  #endif //_DEBUG
}
```

SO:

what is the right way that delete the pointer to a modeless dialog ?

Thank your help!

DONE:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/wtl/message/4444

OnFinalMessage is WTL's equivalent to MFC's PostNCDestroy and you can
safely let your frame window "suicide" in there :)

```
void CSetRecordInfoDlg::OnFinalMessage( HWND /*hWnd*/ )
{
    delete this;
 }
```

that works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OnFinalMessage is WTL's equivalent to MFC's PostNCDestroy and you can
safely let your frame window "suicide" in there.

refer:
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/wtl/message/4444

Answer (score 0):

Per the MSDN documentation:

> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ex01tfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
>
> "The default handlers call the EndDialog member function to close the
>   dialog window.  You can also call EndDialog from your own code...
>
> "To arrange for closing and deleting a modeless dialog box, override
>   PostNcDestroy and invoke the delete operator on the this pointer."

Comment: Yes... I did this  But when delete it . function  ~CWindowImplRoot()   assert line will be hit... could you just have a try for help ... thanks.